# Problem with makefile , "make: Nothing to be done for 'all' " [C]

Tags: c, makefile

I made this little makefile.
Its job is to compile 2 separate files.
The first file makes use of threads.

When I launch it, however, the terminal tells me:
"make: *** No rule to make target 'bank.c', needed by 'bank'. Stop."

```
CFLAGS = -Wall
CC = gcc
LP = -lpthread

all: cash bank

bank: bank.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o bank bank.c $(LP)

cash: cash.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o cash cash.c
```

Comment: Look closely at `bank .c`

Comment: i noticed but the problem persists

Comment: Then make is not finding that file. Make sure it is named exactly the same and in the same directory

Comment: It is located in the same directory and is called "Makefile". I launch it with the command "make -f Makefile.mak"

Comment: If your makefile is called `Makefile` why are you running make with `-f Makefile.mak`?

Comment: because otherwise he won't find it ...
It has this kind of extension because I created the makefile with visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

> No rule to make target 'bank.c',

This indicates that 1) `bank.c` is required, 2) it doesn't exist, and 3) there's no rule to generate it.

That `bank.c` is required is expected.

That there is no rule to generate it is normal. `.c` files aren't usually generated.

So the question is, why doesn't `bank.c` exist?

Comment: sorry now I corrected it ... I had the file which was called bankk.c instead of bank.c ...
But now he tells me: make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

Comment: Then that means that the prerequisites of `all` are up to date and make doesn't think anything needs to be done.  In this case it means a file `bank` exists and is newer than `bank.c`, and a file `cash` exists and is newer than `cash.c`

Comment: So do you think it would be okay?
In my opinion not ... I did a test, and I deleted the executables I had previously produced (without the make).
I then ran make, but did not create any executables.

Comment: You can use `-B` to force a build. But the whole point of `make` is to avoid needless building.

Comment: Re "*I then ran make, but did not create any executables.*", What error did it give?

Comment: No, when you deleted `bank` and `cash`

Comment: what I wrote above appears

Comment: No, `make` won't say that if they exist, and I trust it more than I trust you. Anyway, if you have new questions, the comments of an answer is not the place to ask them

Comment: I just wanted to try to solve this problem ...
I don't understand why it gives me "make: Nothing to be done for 'all'. in output

Comment: Again, the comments is not the place to ask new questions.  And for good reason. People tend to give little to no information. And this is no exception "it gives me "make: Nothing to be done for 'all'. in output" is not an adequate description of a problem. In fact, that's the message one gets when everything works fine! The question that was asked has been answered. Then you edited your post to ask a different question, and that one was also answered. If you have a third question, post a new Question.